# Как доставать элементы из selector?

Tags: javascript

Как доставать элементы из selector?
Чтобы выглядело примерно так(при клике на опцию добавлять вот такой блочок):

```css
p {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select id="secectorOne">
  <option value="80">80см</option>
  <option value="90">90см</option>
  <option value="120">120см</option>
  <option value="140">140см</option>
  <option value="160">160см</option>
  <option value="180">180см</option>
</select>
<p>90см &times;</p>
<p>80см &times;</p>
<p>100см &times;</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addblock(el) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = el.querySelectorAll("option")[el.selectedIndex].textContent;
  el.parentNode.appendChild(p);

}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select id="secectorOne" onchange="addblock(this)">
  <option value="80">80см</option>
  <option value="90">90см</option>
  <option value="120">120см</option>
  <option value="140">140см</option>
  <option value="160">160см</option>
  <option value="180">180см</option>
</select>
<p>90см &times;</p>
<p>80см &times;</p>
<p>100см &times;</p>
```